# The server can't connect to AD DC on 389 port

Tags: windows, active-directory, ldap

I have a problem with the server in our AD Environment. All other servers work fine, but this server can’t connect to the domain controllers. When I’ve tried to ping DC from this server by FQDN, it’s ok. But when I’ve tried run telnet to DC with 389 or 53 ports it wasn’t working. Even if I’ve tried run telnet command to other server (not DC) with 80 port it’s faild also. So I decide that the problem with network on this server and I’ve tried restart its. But this also didn’t work.

Could anyone help me? Thanks in advice!

Comment: Are the server and domain controller on the same subnet?

Comment: Yes, all of them in the same subnet.

Comment: Maybe something is blocking ports, double check router, firewall, etc.

Comment: I’v checked it many times, but all of this seems ok.

Comment: Try using NLTEST.EXE from your server to test the secure channel with the domain. That would be the /SC_QUERY:<domainname> switch. If it comes back with access denied, you may need to rejoin the domain.